Whats the best way to stop and start selenium webdriver to prevent detection?
I would like to disconnect webdriver from the broswer when not in use and performing clicks (using a python mouse gui to click with x,y coordinates) to reduce the chance my bot or selenium from being detected. In order to achieve this I'm using driver.disconnect() and driver.connect() from seleniumbase (which uses service.start() and service.stop()), the driver is also initiated with a fake user-agent (this is done automatically by seleniumbase) to prevent initial detection, and from the author's github:
https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/seleniumbase/undetected/__init__.py
we can see exactly what driver.disconnect() and driver.connect() does:
driver.disconnect():
def disconnect(self):
        """Stops the chromedriver service that runs in the background.
        To use driver methods again, you MUST call driver.connect()"""
        if hasattr(self, "service"):
            try:
                self.service.stop()
            except Exception:
                pass
            time.sleep(0.012)

driver.connect():
def connect(self):
        """Starts the chromedriver service that runs in the background
        and recreates the session."""
        if hasattr(self, "service"):
            try:
                self.service.start()
            except Exception:
                pass
            time.sleep(0.012)
        try:
            self.start_session()
        except Exception:
            pass
        time.sleep(0.012)

My code/attempt is as follows:
with SB(uc=True, ad_block_on=True, incognito=True, do_not_track=True, maximize=True, extension_dir="ext") as sb:
    url = "https://www.example.com/"
    sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 4)
    wait = WebDriverWait(sb.driver, 10)
    sb.driver.disconnect()
    
    #Connect webdriver before performing selenium action(s), example:
    sb.driver.connect()
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, my_xpath)))
    #disconnect after action(s) are performed
    sb.driver.disconnect()

The above works well majority of the time, however occasionally it fails and produces the following errors:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 715, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 244, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\client.py", line 1336, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\client.py", line 1382, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\client.py", line 1091, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\client.py", line 1035, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001F3BDCBA1B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\sb_test.py", line 354, in <module>
    print(f'after function: {post_button.text}')
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 90, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 395, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 352, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 302, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 322, in _request
    response = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 77, in request
    return self.request_encode_url(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 99, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 376, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 827, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 827, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 827, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 799, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=61788): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/b408edfdfe5527eeea10474b020410c5/element/f.82FA29D20D3690B03EAF9BB58E80412A.d.57781E4F7DCA9BCA6EA5196EDA232CF3.e.34/text (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001F3BDCBA1B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

Process finished with exit code 1

Is there a better way to disconnect the webdriver from the browser and is doing so enough to prevent selenium from being detected?

that won't do anything for bot detection. The browser is launched in dev-mode and bot-detection can read that right in the user-agent.  (I suppose a site who scans/probes localhost and hacks out the port, might actually be able to send commands to the webdriver?  I'm thinking there are some protections in place there in the driver as the "only local connections allowed" text suggests...)  The error is probably the driver or browser rejecting a new connection because there are too many websockets still open?  Just a guess.  It's hard to know when to close/dispose of a socket.

I believe seleniumbase (which I'm using) auto generates a fake/valid user-agent when launching the driver and I can also always add my own custom user-agent. My motivation for disconnecting the webdriver before performing actions is that I believe some sites checks for selenium after ie. a click is performed like for example cloudflare CAPTCHA detects either Selenium in the browser or JavaScript involvement in clicking the CAPTCHA. The seleniumbase author reported this recently on his github: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/issues/2865

those would be handled via wire protocol... the driver has to use it to send any commands at all.... unless using dev protocol... either way if the driver has stopped it's service no commands will go through.

ahhh... I see after reading that issue they're using a robot-like framework for clicking.  That's a way around it I suppose.  Not sure you have to worry about an idle driver, though.  Either it's sending a command/receiving a response or not.  I'll look at the code quoted there to see if they can detect wire protocol.  Once wire protocol is started not real sure if it ever loses it's hooks in DOM until the browser is closed.

brotector isn't doing any csrf style probing there, so at least that bit doesn't check if webdriver server is running locally.  Might as well do this all from robot-like framework if you really want to get around bot detection.  (though you should be a good internet citizen and not run bots on sites that include bot detection... it's presumed that they don't want you to do that... maybe ask permission first or inquire about a public API)

Another option is to create/derive your own browser that builds in some of the protections against detection.  That brotector is doing some things that detect the sort of synthetic events that wire protocol generates.  The problem then becomes behavior based things... during the run more data on how bot-like your behavior has been is collected.  People have a certain amount of chaos in their actions which a bot can never have... though you might hookup a bunch of lava lamps or something to bring in some true randomness.  (or keep asking chatgpt what to do next)

The websites I'm dealing with actually don't seem to deploy bot prevention mechanisms but I don't know how much they log or can detect to use to ban you after. I just want to automate posting my listings to online selling sites or post to my social media accounts to save time. The problem is their bot related policies is really vague and even when contacting support to inquire, I'm given a different answer each time. There's also many paid 3rd party automation services to post on these sites so I'm assuming it is tolerable or would you say its not worth the risk of having my account banned?

Thank you, I'll look into robot-like framework and possibly creating my own broswer (although doing so is probably too advanced for me atm). Would you say disconnecting the driver using driver.discconnect()/driver.service.stop() has any validity in preventing selenium from being detected? Also if I'm understanding you correctly, are you saying websites can detect if a host is running selenium by communicating with the host’s webdriver via the wire protocol so if the driver is stopped then there’s no way for the website to communicate with the host's driver and detect selenium?

it's impossible to say as it's a black box and is a moving target.  I only looked at the code for brotector.  That particularly code base does nothing to communicate with the driver, so stopping/disconnecting the service would do nothing there.  And since you have to start the service to send any commands anyway, those detections, if they were in place, would probably detect you anyway.  I'd think most of it is testing for injections/hooks, checking user-agent and testing the events triggered by the driver.  (Event isTrusted, pointer position before/after click, etc...)

If you disconnect the driver before the page load, then you can use pyautogui to successfully click a CF checkbox. (As mentioned in https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/issues/2865). Note that SeleniumBase does a lot more than just that to prevent detection. It modifies chromedriver, sets a lot of settings, launches the browser before attaching chromedriver to it, etc.
